Is it valid to marry a person with whom you committed zina?
Before marriage I and my husband had non penetrative zina on video calls, Is my marriage valid?

A Nikah is which fulfills all the obligation which are
Permission of bride's Wali
Acceptance of the proposal by Bride
Assigning of Mahr
Two Male Witnesses
If your Nikah fulfills all these conditions. It is valid.
The act you mentioned doesn't invalidate your Nikah.
But both of you should repent and ask for forgiveness.

Sex chat through internet is not zina (formication) as there is no physical contact. But it is better to avoid sex chat over internet, if they are leaked it will be shame to you and your family.

Say: the things that my Lord has indeed forbidden are: shameful deeds,
whether open or secret; sins and trespasses against truth or reason;
assigning of partners to Allah, for which He hath given no authority;
and saying things about Allah of which you have no knowledge. Quran
7:33

if you happen to do shameful deeds you can always increase the good deeds so that they will be erased as mentioned in this hadith.

A man kissed a woman and then came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and told
him of that, so this Divine Inspiration was revealed to the Prophet
(ﷺ) 'And offer Prayers perfectly at the two ends of the day, and in
some hours of the night; (i.e. (five) compulsory prayers). Verily, the
good deeds remove the evil deeds (small sins) That is a reminder for
the mindful.' (11.114) The man said, Is this instruction for me only?'
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "It is for all those of my followers who
encounter a similar situation." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4687

